# Is there any method to display value of variable in the expression before evaluating it in sympy in Python?

Tags: python, sympy

I am working on a small program on sympy in python.

My problem:

- i want  get the values  of this expression `2*x+3*y+5*z` using random values of x,y,z.
- i want output to be like

  ```
  2*x+3*y+5*z
  2*1+3*2+5*5   for any arbitary value of x=1,y=2,z=3
  33
  ```

My attempt:

```
from sympy import *

init_printing(use_unicode=True)
x,y,z=symbols('x,y,z')
expr=2*x+3*y+5*z
x=1,y=2,z=5
print(expr)
print(expr.subs([(x,1),(y,2),(z,3)],evaluate=False)
print(expr.subs([(x,1),(y,2),(z,3)])**
```

This does not display `2*1+3*2+5*5`
i will be thankful if you can help me out.

Comment: Please state what it does display. I'm not familiar with sympy but I'm sure `x=1,y=2,z=5` doesn't work. And you're missing a parenthesis on the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UnevaluatedExpr` to prevent the Rationals from combining:

```
In [10]: x,y,z=symbols('x,y,z') 
    ...: expr=2*x+3*y+5*z 
    ...: U = UnevaluatedExpr 
    ...: print(expr) 
    ...: print(expr.subs({x:U(1),y:U(2),z:U(3)},evaluate=False)) 
    ...: print(expr.subs({x:U(1),y:U(2),z:U(3)},evaluate=False).doit())                                                                        
2*x + 3*y + 5*z
2*1 + 3*2 + 5*3
23
```